# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on OSX app

Tags: macos

i am testing OSX application that fetch remote server links like https://www.google-analytics.com/collect.

```
  I have found many questions about that but can't find match answer for that .The error i am getting are
```

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>         Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

```
    App use "APP SANDBOX" with "com.apple.security.network.server" set to true , all normal http links are working except secure https links.
```

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to true as well.

```
   What i found so far is if APP PROJECT is turn on "ENABLE DEVELOPER SIGNING" , it doesn't work.
```

However if APP PROJECT is turn off "DEVELOPER SIGNING" , it work.

Any idea what it could be and how to solve?

Regards,
John

Comment: OMG i have the same problem at the moment, did you manage to fix this? pls share how. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I already found out why,
I [answered the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833746/enable-developer-signing-fails-server-request-macos/51855626#51855626)

Technically you need to check the

> Outgoing Connections

from **Capabilities>App Sanbox**