# Enable Developer Signing Fails Server request MacOS

Tags: macos

I have an app that calls API request from the server that works perfectly before adding developer signing Cert.

After enabling the Developer Signing, i always get failure server request

**finished with error - code: -1003**

any idea why i get this?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: we have the same issue with this developer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684621/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-osx-app

Answer (score 1):

I already know why i get the issue. My App request from server and it is sandboxed. I need to enable the *Outgoing Connections* insdie the Capabilities>App Sandbox to successfully request from server

As per apple docs [Like here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2)

> you need the Outbound Connection capability because the app is
>   initiating the connection. An app acting as a server would require the
>   Inbound Connection entitlement.